# WinEdt how can I move to the previous position of cursor

Tags: positioning, winedt

What is the keyboard combination that takes me to previous/next position of the cursor in WinEdt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Ctrl+Shift+Bkspace for moving backwards and Ctrl+Shift+Del for moving forward.

Comment: You can accept own answer.